# How to stop logcat from scrolling in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I used Eclipse before and I could easily stop logcat from scrolling, but I can't find same funcionality in Android studio. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: If you click on the logcat output before scrolling it should stop automatically scrolling.

Comment: Such an annoying and obvious little bug.

Comment: As stated in @taotao's answer: Triple click the line & voilla!

Comment: None of the answers work in Windows running Android Studio 1.1.0 against a real device (S5). Has nobody at Google even tried to use this tool to write an Android app? This is the same stuff other tech giants have always done: release junk but not use it themselves. "Eat their own dog food". Google became Microsoft.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There's no dedicated button for this, but you can just click on / highlight some text around where you want to stop scrolling.

Comment: I tried it and sometimes it stops scrolling and sometimes it doesn't, it is weird. But afterall, it would be nice to have a button that just stops it because I don't want to be forced to quickly move my mouse to logcat and start highlighting text in order to stop it from scrolling.

Comment: You can click at the bottom of the logcat output to re-enable the scrolling.

Comment: @Drag0 In my case, it only stops scrolling on click while in debug mode. If you simply run it won't work.

Comment: That's really, really poor implementation, and frustrating.  Sometimes you can have a lot going on, and only spot an error when it's flying by during auto-scrolling, and to focus on it, to be able to click the line you want, you have to scroll up.  Many times when scrolling up, to *find* the line you want to click on, it scrolls to the end again.  Why not just have a dedicated button?

Comment: pretty poor effort from Google/JetBrains.. A pause button should be obvious right ? What else do the kids over at Google expect ? I have to yank the device out of the USB to ensure no more scrolling... The free pizza and coke has addled their brains..

Comment: This is no longer true, Sept 29, 2019. Scrolling will not stop as it used to. AS 3.5. See my other comment below.

Comment: This DOES work *IF* you have already set **Show only selected application** in the dropdown menu at far right of Logcat, which likely says "No Filters" or some custom filter..

Comment: I'm sorry to say DSLomer64, but you are wrong. It does NOT work. I agree seaders, it is poor implementation. but to be fair you can't expect Google to ever get it right. They don't have the resources to manage a bugfix like this.

Answer (score 28):

android studio have this feature [image]

you just click on the line three times and you can selectd the line , it will stops scrolling.

Comment: Works! still though the line will wobble up a down sometimes. Nice 'catch'

Comment: Doesn't work here (1.2.2). I click, cursor hangs out in the buffer... then the whole thing reloads, and throws me back to the bottom. And I break a random item on my desk. (Not much left, at this point.)

Comment: This worked for me, however I had to select "No Filters" rather than "Show only selected application" because I was try to get logs from a constantly crashing application.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Simple solution:

In Android monitor, on the right, change **No Filters** -> **Show only selected application**.

Comment: THIS should be THE Answer. AS 3.5; 9/29/19

Comment: THIS should be THE Answer!

Comment: This has been stupid like this since 2013? And is still stupid in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

**Android Studio Stop scrolling log**

1. Disable `Scroll to the end` [image]
2. If not - you are able to scroll to necessary line manually and LogCat will not be automatically scroll to down

Answer (score 1):

I actually just had a problem (in 1.2.2) where I couldn't keep it from scrolling. I tried all the tricks and proper methods mentioned here, but it kept scrolling out from under me.

Turns out there was a problem trying to connect to an emulator that had long since been disconnected, and it kept retrying. And every time it did, it reloaded **everything** causing logcat to refresh.  So it wasn't REALLY scrolling, it just felt like it was because of how big the buffer is.

I unplugged my physical device (that was running along side the emulator), restarted Android Studio, plugged the physical device back in, and *boom*, it no longer kept "scrolling".

Hopefully this might help someone else. Because I was getting incredibly frustrated for a while, there.

Answer (score 0):

Goodness, the trick is to search. Search for something within LogCat and then scrolling will stop. Tested: running Android Studio 1.1.0 against a real device (S5). Also, was ticking one line up and one back down until I then right clicked. Then it totally stopped. After that, I can remove the search and the scrolling is no longer automatic.

Comment: "Oct 18 '13"  Are you kidding me?  Does Android Studio not have a Product Manager or does Google just not give a flip about the dev community. "Be Evil"!